# No Template Found for Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I've tried every possibility I can think of but just keep getting the same error when sending data through a form to a rails mailer. Any idea why I'm getting the "No template found for MailerController#sign_up" response at the bottom?

routes.rb

```
scope '/mailer' do
  post '/signup' => 'mailer#sign_up'
end
```

app/controller/mailer_controller.rb

```
class MailerController < ApplicationController
  def sign_up
    #Create user object
    @user = {  first_name: params[:first_name],
              last_name: params[:last_name],
              email: params[:email],
              package: params[:package_type],
              username: params[:username],
              followers: params[:followers],
              age: params[:age],
              hashtags: params[:hashtags],
              comments: params[:comments]
            }

    AppMailer.sign_up(@user).deliver_now
  end
end
```

app/mailers/app_mailer.rb

```
class AppMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'redacted_email'

  def sign_up(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: "redacted_email", from: @user['email'], subject: 'Sign Up | IAS')
  end
end
```

app/views/app_mailer/sign_up.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <strong>First Name: </strong><p><%= @user[:first_name] %></p><br>
    <strong>Last Name: </strong><p><%= @user[:last_name] %></p><br>
    <strong>Email: </strong><p><%= @user[:email] %></p><br>
    <strong>Package: </strong><p><%= @user[:package] %></p><br>
    <strong>Username: </strong><p><%= @user[:username] %></p><br>
    <strong>Current Followers: </strong><p><%= @user[:followers] %></p><br>
    <strong>Age: </strong><p><%= @user[:age] %></p><br><br>
    <strong>Hashtags: </strong><p><%= @user[:hashtags] %></p><br><br>
    <strong>Comments: </strong><p><%= @user[:comments] %></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

server response

```
Started POST "/mailer/signup" for ::1 at 2017-10-23 15:15:48 -0400
Processing by MailerController#sign_up as HTML
  Parameters: {redacted but all going through successfully}
  Rendering app_mailer/sign_up.html.erb
  Rendered app_mailer/sign_up.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendering app_mailer/sign_up.text.erb
  Rendered app_mailer/sign_up.text.erb (0.6ms)
AppMailer#sign_up: processed outbound mail in 395.7ms

Sent mail to redacted@email.com (25.0ms)
Date: Mon, 23 Oct 2017 15:15:49 -0400
To: redacted@email.com
Message-ID: <59ee3fe573c8_17c8e3fcc17436908788c@Sephs-MBP-5.fios-router.home.mail>
Subject: Sign Up | IAS
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_59ee3fe529f6_17c8e3fcc1743690877b7";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


----==_mimepart_59ee3fe529f6_17c8e3fcc1743690877b7
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Mail unable to send. Please contact IAS Support.

----==_mimepart_59ee3fe529f6_17c8e3fcc1743690877b7
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <strong>First Name: </strong><p>redacted</p><br>
    <strong>Last Name: </strong><p>redacted</p><br>
    <strong>Email: </strong><p>redacted</p><br>
    <strong>Package: </strong><p>$25/mo | Basic</p><br>
    <strong>Username: </strong><p>redacted</p><br>
    <strong>Current Followers: </strong><p>58.5k</p><br>
    <strong>Age: </strong><p>1</p><br><br>
    <strong>Hashtags: </strong><p>hash tagsss</p><br><br>
    <strong>Comments: </strong><p>commentssss</p>
  </body>
</html>

----==_mimepart_59ee3fe529f6_17c8e3fcc1743690877b7--

No template found for MailerController#sign_up, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 484ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are missing the view for the **controller** not for the mailer. The mailer is working wonderfully. The issue is that you are sending the mail through an HTTP POST to the controller. After sending the request, it is not sure what it needs to respond to.

Is this a JS / JSON request to the controller? Adding something like:

`render json: { status: 'ok' }`

to the end of your action should solve the issue.